# What tools can I use to open UML files generated by PhpStorm?

Tags: uml, phpstorm

I've a few `.uml` files (class diagrams mostly) generated by PhpStorm. Are there any other tools that can open these (at least read, if not edit)?

Answer (score 0):

You are lot of tools dealing with UML at visual-paradigm company : [VISUAL PARADIGM](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/) and perhaps community edition available.

Answer (score 0):

If yours files contains XMI serialisation of UML model  i.e. that yours files should start by something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701"> 
<uml:Model etc
```

You just have to find a tool with a UML/XMI import feature. A lot of tool (open, free and commercial) provide this functionality some of them worked together in order to solve possible issue cf [Model Interchange Working Group](http://www.omgwiki.org/model-interchange/doku.php)